# How to Converting Json To HTML Table?

Tags: php, html, json

I have a script that outputs some json.

My json looks like this:

```
{"_get_RoomResult":{"DATA":{"FIELD":[{"F0":"project_no","F1":"room_no"},"",{"F0":"BR1","F1":"A302"},{"F0":"KB2","F1":"1202"}]}}}
```

The structure is like this: (from .asmx):

[image]

How can i convert the data to an HTML table with PHP?

I have tried the following:

```
<?php
                include("lib/nusoap.php");
                $client = new nusoap_client("http://originserv.homeip.net/pap_test2/service1.asmx?wsdl",true); 
                $params = array('KeyWord'=>'1234!@#$%^','Server_Name'=>'Server_Name','Database_Name'=>'PAP_Property','ProgramName'=>'Web_Cust_Room','Program_Module'=>'','Current_User'=>'','PcUser'=>'','PcName'=>'','IP'=>'','User_Version'=>'','Group_Name'=>'ARA','Username'=>'thitima_k');
                $data = $client->call('_get_Room', $params);
                //print_r($data);
                 $result=json_encode($data);
                //print_r($result);
                $mydata = json_decode($result,true); 
?>
```

What should I do next?

I want the output to show like this:

[image]

Comment: OK assuming each object in "FIELD" has same number of properties, any attempt?

Comment: If you don't provide examples of you trying it you should at least provide your expected output.  If we don't know what you want, people's first answers are unlikely to be correct, potentially drawing the question out and most likely resulting in sub questions beyond the scope of what sparked our interest..

Comment: i don't built This XML sir. but i want use php call WebService .NET    with JSon and convert JSon to HTML.

Comment: Show the table you expect for your example data set. Is the data set always the same?

Comment: i want to show like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/qDAts.jpg

Comment: I've reformatted the question. I also added the answer to your question, because it was put on hold and i'm tired of waiting for reopening. I hope this works for you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

How to convert your JSON data to a HTML table?

```
<?php

// json
$result = '{"_get_RoomResult":{"DATA":{"FIELD":[{"F0":"project_no","F1":"room_no"},"",{"F0":"BR1","F1":"A302"},{"F0":"KB2","F1":"1202"}]}}}';

// turn json into array
$data = json_decode($result,true);

// render table
echo "<table>";

// the data to iterate over is in a sub-array
//var_dump($data['_get_RoomResult']['DATA']['FIELD']);

$render_header = true;

foreach($data['_get_RoomResult']['DATA']['FIELD'] as $values)
{
    if(!is_array($values)) continue; // json data contains a string, skip that

    if($render_header === true) {
        echo '<tr><th>' . $values['F0'] . '</th><th>' . $values['F1'] . '</th></tr>';
        $render_header = false; // render header only once
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $values['F0'] . '</td><td>' . $values['F1'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer as correct, when you have enough points.